# Select parents with childs and count of childs for each parent

Tags: mysql, select

I need to select parents with childs and count of childs for each parent by one query.
Now i use next query:

```
SELECT table_a.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_b WHERE table_b.LID=table_a.LID AND table_b.Yes=0) AS Co
FROM table_a 
WHERE table_a.Ind>0 ORDER BY table_a.Ind ASC
```

I think i do it wrong... Is it?

Comment: What made you change the accepted flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you right - you do it the wrong way. even though it works, it is the wrong way for getting the result you like. in order to get the total from one-to-many relationships we use **joins and grouping** for that:

```
SELECT a.ind, count(*) Total 
FROM a JOIN b ON a.lid = b.lid
WHERE a.ind>0 AND b.yes = 0
GROUP BY a.ind
ORDER BY a.ind
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution should work but the subselect get's executed for every row of `table_a` making it a none optimal solution. A better solution would be to `JOIN` both tables and use a `GROUP BY` to get you the same results at a lower performance cost.

```
SELECT table_a.LID
       , COUNT(*) AS Co
FROM   table_a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b ON table_b.LID = table_a.LID AND table_b.Yes = 0
WHERE  table_a.Ind > 0 
GROUP BY
       table_a.LID
ORDER BY 
       table_a.Ind ASC
```

Also, in my opinion, you should always alias your tables and use that alias to make the statement a bit more concise and easier to read.

```
SELECT a.LID
       , COUNT(*) AS Co
FROM   table_a AS a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b AS b ON b.LID = a.LID AND b.Yes = 0
WHERE  a.Ind > 0 
GROUP BY
       a.LID
ORDER BY 
       a.Ind ASC
```